# TSQL GroupBy Max

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a `DocumentHistory` table with this columns:

```
HistoryId   DocumentId    ChangeDate
    1           100       1/1/2005  
    2           100       2/1/2010         
    3           200       2/2/2006 
    4           100       2/2/2001 
    5           200       2/2/2000
```

`HistoryId` is key. 
I want write a `TSQL` query that find Maximum `ChangeDate` of each document and return its `HistoryId`, i mean that query result will be:

```
HistoryId       ChangeDate
    2            2/1/2010
    3            2/2/2006
```

How can i do it?

Comment: This helps [Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [ranking function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx) [`ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ... ORDER BY...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
   SELECT *, 
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DocumentId 
                       ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC) AS RN
   FROM DocumentHistory 
)
SELECT HistoryId, ChangeDate
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1;
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c33be/1)

Comment: @MahmoodGamal : thanks, is it possible that use this query as view?

Comment: @Masoud - Sure, just do `CREATE VIEW viewname as` then put the query, see this [**Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0ebf6/1).

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b.HistoryId,a.ChangeDate from 
(SELECT DocumentId,max( ChangeDate) as ChangeDate
FROM DocumentHistory   GROUP BY DocumentId) a
INNER JOIN DocumentHistory b ON a.DocumentId=b.DocumentId AND a.ChangeDate=b.ChangeDate
```

**this will work on databases without CTE support**
test here http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c33be/16